# MVC routing doesn't pickup querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, query-string

in my Global.ascx.cs, I have this setting for the routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"HomeTarget",
"{TargetCode}",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", TargetCode = "" });

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
```

In my HomeController, I have an Index() action like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Index(string TargetCode)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

When I go to the site, for example, mysite.com/Test1, I suppose it should take "Test1" as the TargetCode, but it didn't... What should I do for it to pickup the "Test1" as TargetCode, I don't want to do this: mysite.com/?TargetCode=Test1

Thank you very much,
Kenny.

Comment: Your example works in a simple ASP.NET MVC application created using the default Visual Studio template and running it under Cassini. So maybe there's something specific in your configuration which prevents it from picking the desired route.

Comment: Apparently there's something wrong with the MVC engine or with VS... I just commented out the code, build the solution, then un-comment the code, and re-build, and everything is working as expected! Thanks for looking Darin.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something's acting up on VS 2008 or with the framework. It's working nicely now. Thanks for looking.