# ASP.NET MVC - Rewriting FormMethod.Get querystring?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, query-string

I have a simple form with just one textbox and one submit button. The form basically sends to a different page with the value in the textbox as querystring. When I click on the submit button, the querystring is in this format, for example:

```
mysite.com/?TargetCode=Test1
```

I would like it to display in this format: `mysite.com/Test1`

I already have an Action in my `HomeController` that take the "TargetCode" as the querystring, and I've already setup a routing in the `Global.ascx.cs` for that. What should I do to re-write the querystring so it doesn't have that "?TargetCode=" in the URL? Here is the code for the form I have:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "CodeForm" }))
```

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573566/mvc-routing-doesnt-pickup-querystring

Comment: Actually my other question was regarding my Index(string Target) action doesn't pickup the querystring, it's now working fine. This question is on how to rewrite my URL. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd have to use jQuery to do the submission otherwise you're dependent on how the browser constructs the URL.  **Updated** to include a hook into the validation plugin.

```
$('#CodeForm').submit( function() {
     var $form = $(this);
     if ($form.valid()) {
        window.location.href = $form.attr('action')
                                  + '/'
                                  + $('[name=TargetCode]').val();
     }
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi tvanfosson, I'm also using jQuery validate library to make sure that the textbox has value in it (required field.) When I use the jQuery function that you posted, it by-passed the validation. Here is what I have:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#CodeForm").validate();

    $('#CodeForm').submit(function() {
        window.location.href = '/' + $('[name=TargetCode]').val();
        return false;
    });
});

Thanks,
Kenny.

Comment: So check if the form is valid before submitting.